# Extract parts of timestamp

Tags: r, postgresql

I have some datasets where animals have been logged each 5th second. the data are stored in postgis and I am using R to analyse and plot the data. I would like to ad on the plots some markers showing the position for each hour. I am pulling subsets of the dataset into R making a data frame having among  other information the timestamp and x and y coordinates for each point.

a part of summary() of my data set (total approx 10000 rows):

```
 id             datetime                        date           
Min.   :2664295   Min.   :2009-08-21 05:00:04   Min.   :2009-08-21  
1st Qu.:2666819   1st Qu.:2009-08-21 08:30:15   1st Qu.:2009-08-21  
Median :2669342   Median :2009-08-21 12:00:03   Median :2009-08-21  
Mean   :2669342   Mean   :2009-08-21 11:30:10   Mean   :2009-08-21  
3rd Qu.:2671866   3rd Qu.:2009-08-21 14:22:44   3rd Qu.:2009-08-21  
Max.   :2674390   Max.   :2009-08-21 16:59:58   Max.   :2009-08-21  

 lokalitet             cowid           x                y          
Length:10          Min.   :553   Min.   :455329   Min.   :6712350  
Class :character   1st Qu.:553   1st Qu.:455718   1st Qu.:6712744  
Mode  :character   Median :553   Median :456154   Median :6713068  
                   Mean   :553   Mean   :456011   Mean   :6713074  
                   3rd Qu.:553   3rd Qu.:456274   3rd Qu.:6713470  
                   Max.   :553   Max.   :456361   Max.   :6713596
```

So, what I would like to do is to subset the data set on datetime where the minute part is 0 and the second part is < 5 (i.e. for the timestamps shown in the summary I would like to have 05:00:04 and 12:00:03. (I know I can do this in postgres, but as the base dataset is quite large (approx 4 M rows) and I have not made an index on partial timestamps, I think it may be better to do this on the subset in R) (and no, as I want to do this a number of times, I do not want to just manually find the first row that matches and then take each 720th row from there on)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, e.g., `dput(head(yourData))`.

Comment: Consider adding some data to http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can all work with the same info

Answer (score 8):

With the `lubridate` package, it is quite easy to extract minutes and seconds from your dates and then to make a test on them. For example :

```
library(lubridate)

## Sample data
dates <- as.POSIXlt(c("2009-08-21 05:00:04","2009-08-21 08:30:15","2009-08-21 12:00:03","2009-08-21 11:30:10","2009-08-21 14:22:44","2009-08-21 16:59:58"))

## How to extract minutes
minute(dates)
# [1]  0 30  0 30 22 59

## How to extract seconds
second(dates)
# [1]  4 15  3 10 44 58

## Select dates from minutes and seconds values
dates[minute(dates)==0 & second(dates) < 5]
# [1] "2009-08-21 05:00:04" "2009-08-21 12:00:03"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a helper function that takes a format string and converts to numeric. I'm going to assume the datatimes are POSIXct rather than POSIXlt. (POSIXct does not play nicely with dataframe operations.)

```
ndtfrm <- function(dt, frm) as.numeric(format(dt, frm))
ndtfrm(dates, "%M")
#[1]  0 30  0 30 22 59
ndtfrm(dates, "%S")
#[1]  4 15  3 10 44 58

 dfrm[ ndtfrm(dfrm$dates, "%M") ==0 & ndtfrm(dfrm$dates, "%S") < 5 , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but it turned out it was easiest to do it in postgres ...

a simple

```
SELECT ..., case when extract(second from datetime)<5 
                         and extract(minute from datetime) = 28 
  then extract(hour from datetime) end as marker  FROM ....
```

gave me what I needed - and as I am just fecthing this data toghether with the rest of the data set, it is no need to search for those points.